# Add from table 2 to table 1 based on minimum measured between the two

Tags: mysql

I have two lists of coordinates, A & B are in table 1

I need to add to table 1, the closest coordinates C & D listed in table 2.

Sample data is here, just a few rows:

dropbox.com/s/meda1j6r6hqlcpj/Sites.csv?dl=0

dropbox.com/s/x64imuez3egd3g9/SLT.csv?dl=0

The calculation is:

```
the square root of
A - C squared 
plus 
B - D squared
```

i.e

```
sqrt(((a-c)^2)+((b-d)^2))
```

I have found this in answer to another question:

```
SQRT( POW(a - c, 2) + POW(b-d, 2) )
```

However, what is the query?

I am a MySQL novice - the above is an application of Pythagoras and the coordinates are Eastings and Northings (of speed traps).

Update:

In addition to that I need to add a constraint for 7 years before to 5 years after. This is measures as -84 to + 59 (months). In the sample data files the following are the fields

WHEN is the date constraint, e.g WHEN in the SLT file is -84< WHEN <59 in the sites file. (Note it's not a date format, it's just an absolute number)

I have made the field names in the sample files match A B C & D, which are all Eastings (A & C) and Northings (B & D)

If I could have both results, i.e. with and without the constraint in the same query that would be ideal.

Processing time is not important as this query will rarely be run, and then only to prove it is accurate.

Comment: What dhould happen if more points from the 2nd table have the same minimum distance to a point in the 1st table?

Comment: good question, highly unlikely (because two cameras cannot occupy the same physical space) but requires a code answer. Choose the one with the earlier install date (field name is INSTALL). However given we think this will never (!)  happen because they can't, use the least complexifying code solution is my 3am suggestion. In fact I am inclined to ask you to just assume they won't - because I don't want the code complicated while I try to understand it. I have another constraint I have not introduced here for the same reason.

Comment: @Anthony500 Point A can have the same distance to point B and point C, even if the coordinates of point B and point C are not equal.

Comment: oh yes! points B and C can be on opposite sides of the same circle because there is no direction vector. Spot on.

Comment: Please post your sample data as code. Here is an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156729/how-to-display-data-in-table-structure-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
where (t2.c, t2.d) = (
    select t3.c, t3.d
    from table2 t3
    order by SQRT( POW(t1.a - t3.c, 2) + POW(t1.b-t3.d, 2) ), t3.INSTALL
    limit 1
)
```

That should work. But i can't test without sample data.

And yes - it can be very slow on huge data. But i'm not sure if there is any faster solution.

Comment: My second constraint is that the accident (table1) happens between 84 months before the install date and 59 months after. I'll link some (real) test data.
This is the “t2” Sites file where are:
C = “EASTING” D = “NORTHING” Install date = “WHEN”
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/meda1j6r6hqlcpj/Sites.csv?dl=0
and
This is a “t1” file SLT where the relevant fields are: 
A = “ACC EC” B = “ACC NC” Date = “WHEN”
The date numbers are whole months so subtracting one from the other gives a number of months for the -84 to +59 constraint.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x64imuez3egd3g9/SLT.csv?dl=0

Comment: I've had it mentioned to me that this has the same effect, though doesn't give the distance, just allows deduction of the shortest distance:(A-C) * (A-C) + (B-D) * (B-D)

Comment: @Anthony500 I don't understand the reason for the "-84 to +59 constraint". But it would be a condition in the subquery `WHERE t3.WHEN BETWEEN t1.WHEN - 59 AND t1.WHEN + 84`. If that doesn't help, you should post some sample data (edit your question) and the expected result - Only columns that matter and only a couple of rows.

Comment: Your second comment is correct - You can skip `SQRT` to increase the performance.

Comment: ok I'll update the Question, thanks for the tip. To answer your question The constraint is 7 years before to 5 years after.

Comment: @Anthony500 i've never asked a question here :-) But this might help you (or me): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thanks - after some lengthy reading, the answer is "click the tick"! Thank you very much for your patient assistance.